# Can’t use fetch to set an arrayList in typescript

Tags: javascript, java, json, typescript, nativescript

### I can't set my vehicule object in my vehiculeList using fetch method.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { Config } from "../config";
import { Vehicule } from "./vehicule";

@Injectable()
export class VehiculeListService {
vehiculeList : Array = [];

constructor(private http: Http) {}
load() { //this function is call in a component.ts
  fetch(Config.apiUrl + "index.php?type=vehicules").then(response => {
  return response.json();}).then(response => {
     var vehiculeList;
     for (var item in response) {
       var vehicule = new Vehicule();
       vehicule.id = response[item].id;
       vehicule.registration = response[item].registration;
       this.vehiculeList.push(vehicule);
       console.dir(this.vehiculeList);//Here vehiculeList is full of vehicule
     }return vehiculeList;
     });
  console.dir(this.vehiculeList);//Here vehiculeList is empty.
}
handleErrors(error: Response) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
return Observable.throw(error);
}
}
```

I'm new here and hope that somebody can help me!
Thanks, F

Comment: code indentation makes reading code possible - just sayin

Comment: The function `fetch` is defined where? Btw, it's Vehicle, not Vehicule.

Comment: @Arg0n, the fetch method is a Nativescript method defined in tns-core-modules.d.ts.

Comment: @FChandebois Of course it's empty in the last `console.log`. I think you need to read up on `asynchronous functions`. The `then` part of your code does not get executed until you get a response from the server. Hence, the last `console.log` will run before you have any vehicles.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Arg0n, I'll check this. Is there a way to bypass asynchronous functions?

Comment: @SongOfWood Why would you want to? Just use `callbacks`, `promises` or `observables`. The result of a HTTP request cannot be instantly available. And you don't want your JS to pause execution until it is. By the way, it looks like `fetch` is returning a `promise`, so you may want to go with that.

Comment: @Arg0n thanks mate! I'll work on that ;)